# laravel livewire redirect method problem with wire:loading

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have button component and when it loading it shows spinner (wire:loading) and when not loading it shows icon (wire:loading.remove).

Problem is: when button calls redirect method this button shows nothing. It is like redirect disables component.

```
<button wire:click="trigger" title="{{$text}}" class="btn btn-{{$color}}   float-right " >
    <div >
        <div wire:loading>
            <span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        </div>
        <div wire:loading.remove>
            @if ($icon)
                <i class="fas {{$icon}}"></i>
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</button>



 public function trigger(){

        if(!empty($this->event)){
            $this->emit('show-modal');
            $this->emit($this->event, $this->params);
        }

        if($this->url !== null){
            return redirect()->to($this->url);
        }


    }


Livewire version: [v1.3.3]
Laravel version: [v6.18.35]
Browser: [Chrome]
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior of livewire loading,
It only working on network calls and not on redirection
To solve this, all what you have to do is create you own logic lik this :

```
public $loading = false;

public function trigger(){
  // your code
  if($this->url !== null){
    $this->loading = true;
    // your code
  }
}
```

And in the blade view :

```
@if($loading)
  // show the loader
@endif
```

By doing this, the loading gonna keep show intil the page change